# Prove if $A,B$ are NP-complete then $((a, b) \mid a \in A \lor b \in B)$ is also NP complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Prove if $A,B$ are NP-complete then $((a, b) \mid a \in A \lor b \in B)$ is also NP complete

I can understand why the union and intersection of 2 NP-complete languages are true but for statement above I can't understand why and how to prove.

Answer (score 1):

To prove it is in $\mathsf{NP}$, use both certificates for $A$ and for $B$, and check if one of them is verified.

To prove it is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard, you can find a reduction from $A$ to $L = \{(a,b)\mid a\in A \lor b\in B\}$: since $B$ is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete, it is neither the empty set nor the universal set. Let $x\notin B$ (there exists such an element). Then $a\in A$ if and only if $(a, x) \in L$. The construction is done in polynomial time, because $x$ does not depend on $a$.